# seeking url query parameters for a website

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, search

I was trying this [search.py](https://github.com/bugatsinho/bugatsinho.github.io/blob/master/plugin.video.releaseBB/resources/lib/modules/search.py) code base to scrape that website using [url](https://github.com/bugatsinho/bugatsinho.github.io/blob/master/plugin.video.releaseBB/resources/lib/modules/search.py#L65) along with [search_url](https://github.com/bugatsinho/bugatsinho.github.io/blob/master/plugin.video.releaseBB/resources/lib/modules/search.py#L45). It produces results in json format - how was it achieved using the dev-tools?
I can see that a request was sent using first the *referer_link*

```
headers = {'Referer': referer_link, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

followed by a pause and then the search url with the query key/values

```
html = client.request(url, headers=headers)
```

I am trying to replicate that in the firefox dev-tools but can't seem to get what other query key/value parameters are available to try. How can I obtain them?

I ask with a specific question - I tried a modified version of that search query

https://rlsbb.cc/Home/GetPost?phrase=&pindex=1

and it returns the current posts on the webpage in json but I do not know how to restrict the query to giving just *tv-shows* within a specified period like:
e.g. *category - tv-shows* between *date - 2024-03-01* and *date- 2024-03-02*?

The website does not have any api documentation, at least to my knowledge.
If this can be achieved then scraping html can be avoided as json data is easier to code in python.
Thank you for your attention and time.
OZooHA

Answer (score 0):

ok i observed your json result (https://rlsbb.cc/Home/GetPost?phrase=&pindex=1) but it appears that all of your objects have `"tbl_wp_category":null` as category
so if you are referencing another key please inform me.

but for the date issue you can execute a **for loop** on your array of objects `"results"` and output only the object that has `"post_date"` less than *2024-03-02* and greater than *2024-03-01*

like this:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

# your JSON data
data = {}

final_result=[]
# Convert JSON string to dictionary
results = data["results"]

# Loop through each result
for result in results:
    # Get the post_date as a string
    post_date_str = result["post_date"]
    
    # Convert post_date string to datetime object
    post_date = datetime.strptime(post_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    # Define the start and end date ranges
    start_date = datetime(2024, 3, 1)
    end_date = datetime(2024, 3, 2)
    
    # Check if post_date is between start_date and end_date
    if start_date <= post_date <= end_date:
        final_result.append(result)
```

Comment: I am not looking for python code but the actual **value** for the **key** parameters _tbl_wp_category_ and _wp_post_date_ to filter out at the url query level.

Comment: The provided code lacks a filter for specific keys, which may be necessary depending on your requirements. You can modify the code to include such filtering to address your specific needs

Comment: I know but that is my question - how can one find those keys and values to filter it out at the result level i.e. preprocessing not post-processing using python like you have done.